# Is it okay, that generic from hook useParams require string?

Tags: typescript, react-router, react-router-dom

[image]

I want to set an object to destruct, but useParams require string. Before react-router@v6 i use @types/react-router. Using this package it was able to set an object to generic. But now there are own types in package react-router.

Comment: please dont use images. Copy and paste minimum reproducible example into your question

Comment: ok, catched it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. It is okay. We just need to use generic like <"id", "name">